# What exactly gets deleted when removing Google account

Tags: google-account, stock-android

When I try to remove my Google account I get the message that messages, contacts and other data from the phone will be deleted.

What does messages include?
Mail messages, SMS, Whatsapp,...?

And what is meant by other data?
All apps, pictures,...?

I'd like to know this for Android 4.4.2 and 4.1.1.

Thank you

Comment: What Android version is running on the device? From the message, I assume it must be lower than 4.x – which means, as it is a phone, something like 2.x? Behavior here is different between Android versions.

Comment: My phone is 4.4.2 but I'd also like to know it for 4.1.1 which a friend got. Actually wanted to help here by removing her account, but I got the said warning and stopped.

Comment: I've never tried myself, but AFAIK with 4.x nothing should get deleted when removing your account except for, umm, your account itself – i.e. name and credentials, sync-options, and the like (on earlier versions, it would delete all data connected to the accounts, such as contacts, calendars, etc). I better leave the answer to somebody having better expertise in this field, though. But one thing for sure: Whatsapp should have nothing to do with it (neither other apps you've installed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently removed the Google account on phones with Android 4.4.2 and 4.1.1.

As far as I can judge nothing got deleted.